# FTP Server on Windows 7 Running WAMP

Tags: windows-7, file-sharing

We are using a Windows 7 machine as our test server. The machine is configured with a static IP and WAMP is running for our PHP Sites. we can access the test sites from internet. Could you tell me how I can make the WAMP's www directory available through FTP or any other file sharing protocol in Windows 7?

Kind regards

Khuram Javaid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question should be on serverfault.
Anyway, you may run a FileZilla ftp server : http://filezilla-project.org/

Answer (score 0):

You could use [CompleteFTP Free](https://enterprisedt.com/products/completeftp/free/).  It's supports FTP and FTPS, has unlimited users and is free.